# Как для формы установить родителя из другого процесса?

Tags: c#, winforms, marshal

Я хочу для формы MyForm установить родителя из другого процесса. И открыть модально, чтобы только при закрытии MyForm был доступ к форме родительсвого процесса.
Мой текущий код:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

Process parentProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApp").FirstOrDefault();
if (parentProcess != null)  
{     
    IntPtr mainHandle = parentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    IntPtr currentHandle = this.Handle;
    SetParent(currentHandle, mainHandle);
}
```

в общем, не знаю где косяк...

Comment: `childWindow.ShowDialog()` вместо `.Show()`

Comment: речь идет о разных процессах

Comment: Вы запускаете `thread.Start()` и в нем открываете новое окно?

Comment: Нет. Обычное приложение Winforms. Есть EXE, которое запустить могу как из главного приложения, так и нет.

Comment: Вам в Marshalling (наверное), я к сожалению не разбираюсь в таком пока что

Comment: Давайте уточним: есть два неких .NET приложения, окно одного приложения должно стать модальным для окна другого приложения. Так?

Comment: да, именно так. Только сделать эту нужно со стороны приложения, окно которого станет модальным

Comment: Тогда одним `SetParent` отделаться не получится: так как "владение" окном переходит другому процессу, то ни о какой модальности речи быть не может и потому придётся задействовать помимо прочего такие WinAPI функции, как `SendMessage`, `EnableWindow` и иже с ними, - иными словами придётся самостоятельно "реализовывать" модальность. С другой стороны, можно обойтись `VirtualProtect` и шелл-кодом, или не изголяться, а просто скрывать нужную форму.